# Probability of being found, while moving or resting

Tags: probability

Let's assume we want to hide ourselves in some 2d matrix.We have the ability to move ourselves instantly ,without revealing our location. In order to find us the enemy has to check each cell in the matrix. There are 2 types of enemies, one that checks the matrix systematically: going cell by cell, or checking every few cells (and then going over the other cells in the next pass).The other enemy checks cells at random location.

What would be the best strategy? hiding or jumping around? feel free to add some other strategies for hiding and seeking.

Comment: Movement is a continuous function? Can you tell where the systematic guy is at any instant?

Comment: you can check a cell, and tell if the enemy has also checked it recently

Comment: Be more precise. What is recently? To check is to move there, or you can just know without moving?

Comment: Yes, you can check without moving, and recently means that someone has checked that cell but you don't know when. note that when you check a cell no one can tell.

Comment: I don't get it. You can check any cell without moving there? This would mean in the beginning you almost certainly know where the enemies are. Later a lot of cells have been visited and the info whether a cell has been visited is useless. Is it like this? Otherwise: Be more precise!

Answer (score 3):

The best strategy is to stay away from the systematic guy, if you can, and don't care about the random guy. The latter will have a probability of finding you no matter what and there's nothing you can do about it.

If you are not able to tell where the systematic guy is, he is as good as random. So the two enemies seem random to you, therefore it doesn't matter which strategy you choose.